# Column ambigously defined in subquery with join on another subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, join, plsql, subquery

I keep getting a column ambiguously defined error when joining two sub queries. However I have defined all my columns properly. I want to get all the data from the first query and add some data to it where available. How can this be fixed?

```
SELECT 
    sq2.month,
    sq1.PRIMARY_MER_NUM ,
    sq1.PRIMARY_EXT_MID ,
    sq1.MER_DBA_NAM, 
    sq1.CLG_NUM, 
    sq1.ENT_NUM, 
    sq1.ENT_NAM, 
    sq1.MER_OPN_DTE, 
    sq1.MER_CLS_DTE, 
    sq1.MER_FST_DPST_DTE,
    sq1.CLG_NUM ,
    sq1.ENT_NUM,
    sq2.gross_volume,
    sq2.transaction_count
FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT
        PRIMARY_MER_NUM ,
        PRIMARY_EXT_MID ,
        MER_DBA_NAM,
        CLG_NUM, 
        ENT_NUM, 
        ENT_NAM, 
        MER_OPN_DTE, 
        MER_CLS_DTE, 
        MER_FST_DPST_DTE,
        CLG_NUM ,
        ENT_NUM 
     FROM
         bi.t_mer_dim_na 
     WHERE
         CLG_NUM = 7
         AND ENT_NUM IN ('45810', '45811', '46849', '45948', '45824',
                         '46911', '45509', '46845', '48902')
    ) sq1
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         TRUNC(BAT_REF_DTE, 'MM') AS month,
         MER_NUM,
         SUM(bat_prd_trn_dr_amt + bat_prd_trn_cr_amt) AS gross_volume, 
         SUM(bat_item_num) AS transaction_count
     FROM 
         TDS.BAT_T3 
     WHERE 
         1 = 1
         AND bat_ref_dte >= TRUNC(sysdate, 'MM') 
     GROUP BY
         TRUNC(BAT_REF_DTE, 'MM'), MER_NUM) SQ2 ON sq1.primary_mer_num = sq2.MER_NUM;
```

Comment: The safest thing is to properly alias all columns involved (I mean, precede every column with its table's alias, not to give an alias to a column). Try to do so.

Comment: Not related, but formatting your queries helps a lot with troubleshooting stuff like this. Mixing UPPER, lower and caMelCase without indentation especially makes it much more difficult to spot errors, in my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have `CLG_NUM` and `ENT_NUM` selected twice in your first derived table `SQL1`

```
FROM (
select DISTINCT
PRIMARY_MER_NUM ,
PRIMARY_EXT_MID ,
MER_DBA_NAM,
CLG_NUM, --1
ENT_NUM, --1
ENT_NAM, 
MER_OPN_DTE, 
MER_CLS_DTE, 
MER_FST_DPST_DTE,
CLG_NUM, --2
ENT_NUM  --2
from bi.t_mer_dim_na
```

That makes selecting `sql1.CLG_NUM` and `sql1.ENT_NUM` ambiguous in your outer select (where you also select both twice)

Comment: What an oversight. Thanks!